# Positioned div doesn't behave as intended

Tags: html, css

The div inside another div won't go to the right but just stays to the left. The code below is some what look like chat box the first div with green background has a position of 0px left and it works but the second div has  0px right and it still stick to the left please help me with this it bothers me for 2 day without right solution

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:100% height:100%; position: relative; top:0px; left:0px; background-color:white;">
        <div style="width:200px; height:100px; position: relative; top:10px; left:0px; background-color:green; font-size:20px;"><p>1</p></div>
        <div style="width:200px; height:100px; position: relative; top:10px; right:0px; background-color:red; color: white; font-size:20px;"><p>2</p></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what result do you want to achieve?

Comment: And you missed a semicolon after `width:100%`

Answer (score 1):

`position: relative` means the div is positioned "relative to itself". So `right: 0px` just means "move the div 0px to the right of where it would normally be"... not to the right edge of the container.

You could use `position: relative` on the container, and apply `position: absolute` to the children instead, but assigning `top` values will be cumbersome.

[Info about `position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

An alternative might be adding `display: flex` to the wrapper. Then you can use `margin-left: auto` to push a div to the right.

```css
.wrapper {
  background: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div > div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left {
  background: green;
}

.right {
  background: red;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent{
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

.incoming {
  float: left;
  max-width: 80%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.reply {
  float: right;
  max-width: 80%;
  background-color: powderblue;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="incoming"><p>Incoming chat that takes up a maximum of 80%
 of screen width.</p></div>
  
  <div class="reply"><p>Reply, that also does the same, but from the right of the screen.</p></div>
</div>
```

Edited to reflect updated requirement

Comment: I basically change the divs to be `position: absolute` instead of `relative`.

Comment: I think that is not the best answer changing the position to absolute if ever I will another green or blue background div it will overlap the previous my explanation was not complete sorry for that I was trying to make a chat box with the recieve message as green div and send message as blue div therefore the number of divs will be increased via ajax jquery

Answer (score 0):

Using `relative` element with `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` properties is useless. you have to change it to `absolute` value.

```html
<div style="width:100% height:100%; position: relative; background-color:white;">
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; position: absolute; top:10px; left:0px; background-color:green; font-size:20px;"><p>1</p></div>
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; position: absolute; top:10px; right:0px; background-color:red; color: white; font-size:20px;"><p>2</p></div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

here is another way to position elements

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:100px; background-color:white;">
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; float:left; background-color:green; font-size:20px;"><p>1</p></div>
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; float:right; background-color:red; color: white; font-size:20px;"><p>2</p></div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE#2**

here is markup for your chat

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.chat {
   width: 100%;
   background: lightblue;
   padding: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.message {
   clear: both;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   color: white;
}
.to, .from {
   width: 40%;
   padding: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.to {
   background: pink;
   float: left;
}
.from {
   background: lightgreen;
   float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
    <div class="message">
        <div class="to">hi</div>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="to">how are u?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="from">fine, thnks</div>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="to">can u help me?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="from">sure, no problem</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: right;` instead of `right:0px;`.

Here is the code.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100% height:100%; position: relative; top:0px; left:0px; background-color:white;">
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; position: relative; top:10px; left:0px; background-color:green; font-size:20px;"><p>1</p></div>
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; position: relative; top:10px; float:right; background-color:red; color: white; font-size:20px;"><p>2</p></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```